# proving that $g(x)=0$ has one real root

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

Given $g(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$,

Need to prove that $g(x)=0$ has one real root.

I thought to use the fact that $e^x<T_{2n}(x)$  for all $x<0$, but it didn't help me.

Thanks.

Comment: induction on degree, and the fact that the derivative is the same without the final term. Always positive with even degree, single real root with odd degree. Been asked here before, several times.

Comment: are sure at the end should be $\frac { { x }^{ 2n+1 } }{ \left( 2n+1 \right) ! } $ not $ \frac { { x }^{ n } }{ n! } \\ $

Comment: Are you sure !? it is a polynomial with odd degree ,so at least has a real root

Comment: i'm sure. that's what it is

Comment: @WillJagy - i didn't understand the induction on degree and the rest. can you expand your comment?

Comment: where did you get the problem?

Comment: just an old small exercise from a notebook before a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
with $n=0,$ we find that $1$ is always positive. With $n=1,$ we find $1+x$ has one real root, namely $-1.$

Induction, two cases, odd/even. For all smaller $n,$ even gives always strictlypositive, odd gives one real root.

If $n$ is odd, we know there is at least one real root. But $f'(x)$ is one of this same family of polynomials, and is always strictly positive. As a result, there is just one real root, the polynomial is negative on the left of that (smaller $x$), positive on the right of it.

If $n$ is even, we know that $f'$ has one real root, negative on the left of that, positive on the right. This means that $f$ has one **global minimum.** Call the $x$ value $x_0.$ We know $f'(x_0) = 0.$ But we also know that
$$  f(x) = f'(x) +  \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$ So
$$  f(x_0) = f'(x_0) +  \frac{x_0^n}{n!}=  \frac{x_0^n}{n!}, $$ with $n$ even. Is it possible to have $x_0 = 0?$ No, as we always have  $f'(0) = 1.$ So, with $n$ even, we have  $x_0^n > 0,$ and $f(x_0) > 0.$

Comment: so it's not important that here my last term is $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$?

Comment: you called yours $g,$ I called mine $f$ so I could write as I wished. Suggest you write this out for small $n,$ show why the quadratic is positive, why the cubic has just one root, and numerically find the root and draw a careful graph.

Comment: yes i know you can:) the question is if i can?... i will try tho. thanks:)

Comment: @don  http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots\\e^x=0,\text{ has no real root}$$but you are trying $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots+\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ it has 1 real root and $2n$ complex roots 
  to make a sense ,see picture above

Comment: thanks but how can i get it without softwares?

Comment: I think ,try to show no root found for $e^x-(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+...+\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!})$ because it is even degree polynomial

Comment: well, that's the problem. to show it.

Comment: Note the proper use of \text{} in MathJax, in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let use induction method:
call

> $${ P }_{ n }\left( x \right) =1+x+\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +\frac { { x }^{ 3 } }{ 3! } +...+\frac { { x }^{ 2n+1 } }{ \left( 2n+1 \right) ! } $$

Hence polynomial with odd degree in $n=0$ ,${ P }_{ 0 }\left( x \right) =1>0\quad \\$ for every  $x\in R$.
Assume it is true for all x,less than $n\epsilon N $.Due to induction method ${ P }_{ n }^{ \prime  }\left( x \right) ={ P }_{ n-1 }\left( x \right) >0\quad \forall x\in R$ ,hence,${ P }_{ n }\left( x \right) $ is increasing and can't equal to zero no more one time.Because of ${ P }_{ n }\left( 0 \right) =1>0\quad $ and $\lim _{ x\rightarrow -\infty  }{ { P }_{ n }\left( x \right) =-\infty  } $ so continuous polynomial function ${ P }_{ n }\left( x \right) $ equel one time to zero. So polynomial function has one real root

Comment: Suggest using \in rather than \epsilon for set membership. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: thank you,i'm working on my english)

Comment: Not a problem with your english. Just trying to help you with MathJax - it can get frustrating at times.